# Camera Preview Not Fitting To UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, avcapturesession

I'm making a camera and I've decided to make it a sort of square like the Instagram camera and the iPhone default camera. I'm encountering a problem where the image doesn't fit the UIView. Below is an example of it happening. The UIView should be covering the red edges to the left and right.

[image]

Here is the code that starts the session...

```
func reloadCamera() {

    cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (camera == false) {
        let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        for device in videoDevices {
            let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front {
                captureDevice = device
                break

            } else {
                captureDevice = backCamera
            }
        }

    } else {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    }

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        if captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds

                captureSession!.startRunning()
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle any errors
        print(error)
    }

}
```

There are no constraint issues whatsoever and I've tried deleting all elements and only having the code up above run but it didn't work. Tell me if you need any more information. Thanks! (:

Comment: Did you try `previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`?

Comment: @ChengYuHsu Yeah I did and it worked but it didn't change how it appears as an image.

Comment: I think you'll need to crop the image based on how you displayed it in the `previewLayer` after capturing it.

Comment: @ChengYuHsu How would I do that?

Comment: Once you know the size of your `previewLayer`, you can crop the image with width remaining the same but the height is calculated by based on the aspect ratio of your `previewLayer`.

For example: if the bounds of the `previewLayer` is {{0, 0}, {370, 370}} and the image is of size {3000, 4000}.

You'll need to crop the image with a rect {{0, (4000-3000)*0.5}, {3000, 3000}} so it will have the same aspect ratio as you expected.

Comment: If the width of my previewLayer is 370, how would I crop the image with code?

Comment: @ChengYuHsu Could you do that as code in an answer so I can accept it?